# Prevent to click on you tube video link in react player

Tags: reactjs, react-player

I am using ReactPlayer https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player in my react project and it is working but issue is when I put any youtube video url then all youtube video series are displaying bottome side of player  and if whenever I click on that youtube video title then it is redirecting to youtube site.

```
<ReactPlayer
 onProgress={() => this.progress(this.state.vid[0].vid.videotext)}
 onEnded={(e)=>this.onEnded(e,this.state.vid[0]._id)}  url={this.state.vid[0].videourl} controls={true} playing={false} />}
```

So I just want to disable that all thing, can it possible using any way ?
Your help would be highly appreciated

Thanks in Advavce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube video was open in an iframe (you will see it by browser inspect), and you can't disable features that was place inside iframe (for security reason).

So if you want to prevent user click to youtube link, you can create an transparent overlay that has z-index larger than your video player, and then user can't click youtube link. Of course, don't overlay play/pause button :')

Comment: how can I create  create an transparent overlay, can you give me any example

Comment: hi, I have reproduced it on stackblitz here is the link can you  have a  look on it https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r6j28k

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rxwrzt, i added example, now user can't click top toolbars.

Comment: Thanks  it worked for me  I am gonna accept your ans but can  just tell me how can I disable you tube video suggestion as well, when I pause video or finihsed then it show me more video of that series

Comment: It same with example above, you must create other overlay that placed exactly same position with youtube suggestion. I used https://github.com/sampotts/plyr and they also do this way :')

Comment: additional, you should only show your overlay when user clicked pause button to avoid annoying user. Using https://github.com/CookPete/react-player#callback-props

Comment: I have gone through your example and this what I have made it can you have look on it https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r6j28k

Answer (score 0):

Try event.preventDefault(); event.stoppropagation(); in click handler.
if not worked post post your code snippet.

Comment: It is not wroking